# Place div block

Tags: html, css

Please tell me there are 3 div blocks. How to place div 3 under div 1?
Placing blocks in places cannot be changed, because div 3 is submitting the form.

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.div3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
  <div class="div1">
    div1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    div2
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display:flex;">
  <div class="div3">
    div3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a job for `CSS Grid`. Have a look at this demo.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-template-columns: 100px 500px;
}

.parent > div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.div2 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">
    div1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    div2
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    div3
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Combine div1 and div3 within one `<div></div>` like this:

```
<div style="display:flex;">
  <div>
    <div class="div1">
      div1
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
      div3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    div2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wrote that the location of the blocks can not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there Game Eagle,

Might i suggest taking a look at CSS-grid ? This allows you to re-arrange content on the site.

Specifically grid-template-areas, which allows you to define areas of your content, and then tell the content which area they belong to.

A good reference that might be handy: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I bet you won't.